# SQL Long String into Substrings by a length and whitespaces

Tags: sql, t-sql

I Want to make out of a String ("Hello this is a String That is very odd")
Substrings by a defined legth (eg. 8) so that when string gets cut at index 8 but alway at the whitespaces not in a word.

lenth : 11
("Hello this is a String That is very odd") --> ("Hello this"),("is a String"),("That is"),("very odd")

I alredy have an array of the indexes Of the whitespaces but i dont know further.

I appreciate if you would help me

Comment: What if the string ='12345678901234567890' and the defined length = 8 ?

Comment: Is not possible in my case. Only real sentences with spaces. And if there are no spaces cut at exactly 8

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. The question is: What if a word is too long? Say for a length of 8: 'Few whitespaces in long-word sentences". What would be the expected result?

Comment: "I alredy have an array of the indexes"- would you please edit the question and share your code we can start with to answer the question?

Comment: Anyway, this is something you don't usually do in SQL. Use a programming language where this is a simple loop. In SQL you perform such iterative processes with recursive queries. Possible but less appropriate for the task in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy solution...
So the simple answer is: Do not use SQL-Server for this issue. It's just the wrong tool.

Nevertheless this can be done (if you have to):

--Some declared table to mock your scenario

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString NVARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Hello this is a String That is very odd')
                      ,('blah')
                      ,('And one withaverylongword');
```

--use this to define the portion's length. 8 will be to little...

```
DECLARE @portionLenght INT = 12;
```

-the query

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t.ID
          ,A.[key] AS fragmentPosition
          ,A.[value] AS fragment
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(t.YourString,' ','","'),'"]')) A
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,fragmentPosition,fragment 
          ,0 AS growingIndex
          ,CAST(fragment AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS growingString

    FROM cte 
    WHERE fragmentPosition=0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.ID
          ,cte.fragmentPosition
          ,cte.fragment
          ,recCTE.growingIndex + CASE WHEN B.newLength>@portionLenght THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ,CASE WHEN B.newLength>@portionLenght THEN cte.fragment ELSE CONCAT(recCTE.growingString,N' ',cte.fragment) END
    FROM recCTE 
    INNER JOIN cte ON cte.ID=recCTE.ID AND  cte.fragmentPosition=recCTE.fragmentPosition+1
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEN(CONCAT(recCTE.growingString,N' ',cte.fragment))) B(newLength)
)
,final AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,growingIndex ORDER BY fragmentPosition DESC) lastGrowing
    FROM recCTE
)
SELECT * FROM final
WHERE lastGrowing=1
ORDER BY ID,fragmentPosition;
```

The result (with length=12)

```
1   Hello this
1   is a String
1   That is very
1   odd
2   blah
3   And one
3   withaverylongword
```

The idea in short

- we use a trick with `OPENJSON` to transform your string into a json array and split it with a guaranteed sort order.
- we use a recursive CTE to run through your fragments.
- each iteration will calculate the total length of the former parts together with the new fragment
- depending on this calculation the fragment will either be added or a new protion is opened.
- the final CTE will add a partitioned `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the *last* entry per portion.

And no, you should not use this... :-)

Comment: Cool trick with `OPENJSON`. Might be wise to do `REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(t.YourString, 'json'),' ','","')`

Comment: @Charlieface true, quotes within the string could break this approach.